# Drawing multiple lines with Java

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm learning Computer Graphics and want to draw lines with Java Swing. I want to draw multiple lines which stays and come with random color and random point of x and y. I can draw a line smoothly without any problem with this code:

```
package tugas1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Tugas1 extends JPanel{
    
    public static int time = 0;
    public static int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    Color randomcolor;
    public Tugas1() {
        this.x1 = (int) (Math.random()*1280);
        this.y1 = (int) (Math.random()*720);
        this.x2 = (int) (Math.random()*1280);
        this.y2 = (int) (Math.random()*720);
        randomcolor = new Color((float)Math.random(),(float)Math.random(),(float)Math.random());
        // Inisialisasi timer untuk animasi
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //menambah value variabel time secara berkala
              time++;
              repaint();
          }
       });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public void garis(Graphics g, int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb){
        int count = 0;
      
        int a = xa;
        int b = ya;
        int dxa = ((xb - xa));
        int dya = ((yb - ya));
        g.setColor(randomcolor);
        if(dxa==0){
            if(dya > 0) {
                while(ya != yb && time>=count) {
                    ya++;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            } else {
                while(ya != yb && time>=count) {
                    ya--;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } else if(dya==0){
            if(dxa > 0) {
                while(xa != xb&& time>=count) {
                    xa++;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            } else {
                while(xa != xb&& time>=count) {
                    xa--;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } else{
            dxa = Math.abs(dxa);
            dya = Math.abs(dya);
            int pk = (dya < dxa) ? 2*dya - dxa : 2*dxa - dya;
            int dp = (dya < dxa) ? 2*(dya-dxa) : 2*(dxa-dya);

            boolean opr1 = (xa > xb);
            boolean opr2 = (ya > yb);

            while(xa != xb && ya != yb && time>=count) {
                if(pk > 0) {
                    if(opr1) xa-=1;
                    else xa+=1;

                    if(opr2) ya-=1;
                    else ya+=1;
                    pk += dp;
                }
                else {
                    if (dya < dxa) pk = pk + 2 * dya;
                    else pk = pk + 2 * dxa;
                    if(dxa>dya){
                        if(opr1) xa-=1;
                        else xa+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        if(opr2) ya-=1;
                        else ya+=1;
                    }
                }
                g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                a = xa;
                b = ya;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
       garis(g, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Gambar");
        fr.setSize(1280,720);      
        Tugas1 panelGambar = new Tugas1();
        fr.getContentPane().add(panelGambar);
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

But when I try to create a multiple line with just one click if a button, let say 100 lines, my button doesn't work (it just create one line, and the animation is dissappear). Here is the lines of my code for creating multiple lines:

```
package tugas1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Tugas1 extends JPanel{

    public static int time = 0;
    public static int x1,y1,x2,y2;
    Color randomcolor;
    public Tugas1(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        this.randomcolor = color;
        // Inisialisasi timer untuk animasi
        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              //menambah value variabel time secara berkala
              time++;
              repaint();
          }
       });
        timer.start();
    }

    public final LinkedList<Tugas1> line = new LinkedList<Tugas1>();
    
    public void garis(Graphics g, int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb){
        int count = 0;
      
        int a = xa;
        int b = ya;
        int dxa = ((xb - xa));
        int dya = ((yb - ya));
        g.setColor(randomcolor);
        if(dxa==0){
            if(dya > 0) {
                while(ya != yb && time>=count) {
                    ya++;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            } else {
                while(ya != yb && time>=count) {
                    ya--;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } else if(dya==0){
            if(dxa > 0) {
                while(xa != xb&& time>=count) {
                    xa++;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            } else {
                while(xa != xb&& time>=count) {
                    xa--;
                    g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                    count++;
                }
            }
        } else{
            dxa = Math.abs(dxa);
            dya = Math.abs(dya);
            int pk = (dya < dxa) ? 2*dya - dxa : 2*dxa - dya;
            int dp = (dya < dxa) ? 2*(dya-dxa) : 2*(dxa-dya);

            boolean opr1 = (xa > xb);
            boolean opr2 = (ya > yb);

            while(xa != xb && ya != yb && time>=count) {
                if(pk > 0) {
                    if(opr1) xa-=1;
                    else xa+=1;

                    if(opr2) ya-=1;
                    else ya+=1;
                    pk += dp;
                }
                else {
                    if (dya < dxa) pk = pk + 2 * dya;
                    else pk = pk + 2 * dxa;
                    if(dxa>dya){
                        if(opr1) xa-=1;
                        else xa+=1;
                    }
                    else {
                        if(opr2) ya-=1;
                        else ya+=1;
                    }
                }
                g.drawLine(a,b,xa,ya);
                a = xa;
                b = ya;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void addLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
        line.add(new Tugas1(x1, y1, x2, y2, color)); 
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        for (Tugas1 lines : line){
           garis(g, lines.x1, lines.y1, lines.x2, lines.y2);
        } 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fr = new JFrame("Gambar");
        fr.setSize(1280,720);      
        final Tugas1 panelGambar = new Tugas1(0,0,0,0, Color.WHITE);
        fr.getContentPane().add(panelGambar);
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
        buttonsPanel.add(startButton);
        fr.getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(int i= 0; i<100; i++){
                    int x1 = (int) (Math.random()*1280);
                    int y1 = (int) (Math.random()*720);
                    int x2 = (int) (Math.random()*1280);
                    int y2 = (int) (Math.random()*720);
                    Color randomColor = new Color((float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random(), (float)Math.random());
                    panelGambar.addLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, randomColor);
                }
            }
            
        });
        fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        fr.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Maybe there's a way to keep the lines drawn are not dissapear and all lines are drawn as the first template of code

Comment: Use some kind of `List` and store all the "lines" you want drawn in it.  Then when `paintComponent` is called, iterate over the `List` and draw each line

Comment: I'd recommend [Java Collections Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html), [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html) and [Java 2D Graphics Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) as some invaluable resources - especially the decision on "shapes" in the 2D graphics trail

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"Use some kind of `List`"* The code declares a `List` e.g. `public final LinkedList<Tugas1> line = new LinkedList<Tugas1>();`. The OP is very confused about attributes and what they should be attached to / how they should be stored. Good advice about the tutorial, if the OP does them, they'll hopefully understand why setting a BG color should be done in the constructor rather than a paint method.

Comment: See: [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a basic working example to get you started. It demonstrates how to store the information about the object to be drawn in a custom object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int x1,y1,x2,y2;
```

1. Don't use `static` attributes unless you can explain why they *need* to be declared static.
2. These attributes are declared as part of the `Tugas1` class. It's a panel. It does not need these attributes and this is part of the problem. Remove them.
3. Wrap the 4 numbers and color in a POJO (let's call it a `ColoredLine`) and add those to a `LinkedList<ColoredLine>`.
4. Then iterate *that* list & paint each one in turn.

Comment: Okay thank you.. Now my code works fine, but can it works like draw another line after a line is done to be drawn?

Comment: *"can it works like draw another line after a line is done to be drawn?"* I'm not sure what you mean by this. DYM that each of the lines should be drawn after a short interval? Something else?

Comment: "_DYM that each of the lines should be drawn after a short interval? Something else?_"
I mean can it be drawn line by line? like queue. Before first line is finished to be drawn, the second line wont be drawn.

Comment: Sure, but it would take either more complex logic, or a different approach (with similarly different, but less complicated, logic) of drawing each added line to a `BufferedImage`. Both would be based around using a Swing `Timer` to draw the later lines. Too complex to go into in comment. I suggest you ask a new question & include a [mre] of any attempt you've made.